# Blocking a Message Queue (RabbitMQ/SQS)

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, amazon-sqs

I have an application in which I concatenate videos together to form longer and longer montages. I am trying to use a queue to carry the concatenation jobs, but I've encountered an issue.

I cannot have two videos trying to be concatenated to the same video at once (or else I will lose data), so a normal queue won't work (I have multiple transcoding servers).

I think I need a queue that supports 'blocking' (ie. while I'm working on concatenations to this video, block all other attempts to pull concatenation jobs off this queue until I am done). I would then have a separate queue for each target video, which would probably necessitate dynamically creating queues as new videos that will be the targets of concatenation come in.

I have looked into RabbitMQ for this. It seems like it might work, because it supports 'exclusive' connections. The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way to get a list of all available queues, so now I don't know how to deal with pulling off dynamically generated queues.

I would greatly appreciate feedback on how to approach this problem. Am I totally off base?

Comment: A MQ is just send simple message , you can put tons of meta data in the message and your program logic to ensure data integrity.  You should expect a "order" in the message queue services. A queue is just FIFO.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to Block, you just want to avoid processing a particular video segment if something else is already doing so.  You probably want to implement this with a failure and retry.  This is implemented slightly differently in [SQS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html) vs [RabbitMQ](http://dev.venntro.com/2014/07/back-off-and-retry-with-rabbitmq/).

Basically, you will want a lock that you can create on the video, if someone else owns the lock, you want to fail the message, and, after a certain timeout, try again.  You will want to set the delay and retry high enough for worst-case scenarios (max processing time * max # of segments), and put in a [dead letter queue](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQSDeadLetterQueue.html) to handle the ultimate failures.

There are lots of good [Distributed Locking](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=distributed%20lock) implementations out there.

Answer (score 1):

The [RabbitMQ management client](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) plug-in has an api to get a list of all available queues: `/api/queues`

Follow the link to the API on that page for more detail (haven't placed link in answer because link will fast go out of date with new API releases).